# invalid syntax - kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Learning kivy for the first time and faced a problem while starting `.kv` file.

**main.py**:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class Grid(Widget):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

**file.kv**:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<Grid>:
    Label:
        text: "Hello World!"
```

**error code**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\megaa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\megaa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main        
    run()
  File "c:\Users\megaa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.12.424452561\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file    
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "d:\python\kivy\tutorial\tutorial2\file.kv", line 1
    <Grid>:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would even load file.kv. Your error looks suspiciously like you're trying to run it as a python file. Can you explain exactly what you're doing?

Comment: I did everything like it was in yt tutorial. When I run python file everything works properly, but when I run kivy file, receive this error. You mentioned that there is nothing in my code that would load file.kv, how to do it?

Comment: The kv file isn't python code, you can't run it with a python interpreter and should instead load it via your python file. Either you misunderstood your youtube tutorial, or it is wrong. Read the kivy documentation or a better tutorial to see how kv files work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that your .kv file is an design file. we have to load it in the python script.

In order to do that, Please do following in *main.py*

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder # new line added 

class Grid(Widget):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('file.kv') # change here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

Now .kv file is loaded and should provide expected output.

***Happy Learning***

Edit 1:

Remove brackets and it should be running.
In *file.kv*

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
Grid:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Hello World!"
```

Edit 2:
My *main.py* file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder # new line added 

class Grid(Widget):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('file.kv') # change here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

Output Kivy window:
![output_kivy_window][https://imgur.com/a/819K20A]

Comment: ok, but starting .kv file anyway returns me error that have been mentioned above

Comment: <Grid>: is a rule, Grid: is an root widget. To understand difference check [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html]

So, In your original .kv file, widget defined and you apply the rule to the non-existent widget which produced an error. with this edit, root widget came to existent

Comment: (latest code change): doesn’t work, “Syntax Error ^ Grid:”

Comment: Same Error? It works perfectly for me. Check for mixed indentations. Should contain either tabs or spaces in .kv file

Comment: Just copy paste my .py and .kv code and run it and check imgur link for my output window

Comment: well, it works. Still don't understand what was a mistake in my code

Comment: i mean i took your code and tried it and it returned me a mistake, so little confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227607/discussion-between-rorschach-and-lcashe).